# Arch Linux with Xfce-Desktop no longer starts

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I run Arch Linux with XFCE. Recently, I decided to switch to PCmanfm as my file manager. I removed Thunar with:

`pacman -Rc thunar`

and rebooted. Now when I try to log in, my XFCE4 desktop flashes for a second, then returns to my login manager (Slim).  Reinstalling thunar does not help. 
How can I get my desktop working again? It's okay if it's with thunar for now, I just need a working setup, PCmanfm will come later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `-c` switch unless you really are sure of what you are doing. From `man pacman`:

> -c, --cascade
>              Remove all target packages, as well as all packages that depend on one or more target packages. This operation is recursive, and *must be used with care* since it can remove many potentially needed packages.

You have obviously removed a needed package (or packages). Look back through your `pacman.log` and see what packages were removed along with thunar and then reinstall them until you are back at your old set up.

In future, to remove dependencies, use the `-s` switch:

> -s, --recursive
>              Remove each target specified including all of their dependencies, provided that (A) *they are not required by other packages*; and (B) they were not explicitly installed by the user. This operation is recursive and analogous to a backwards --sync operation, and helps keep a clean system without
>              orphans.

Comment: It looks like I uninstalled
xfdesktop
thunar-volmon
thunar-media-tags-plugin
thunar-archive-plugin
When I reinstalled these, it downloaded nothing, I figured they all installed when I did 
pacman -S thunar
before. The error persists after reinstallation.

Comment: `pacman -S thunar` is not a direct reversal of `pacman -Rc thunar` - make sure there is nothing else in the log. If not, then you will need to look through Slim's log (and probably Xorg.0.log) to determine why XFCE isn't loading.